# Как вставить строку в таблицу, если ее там еще нет

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

я знаю два варианта для выполнения `INSERT IF NOT EXIST`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys where name='web')
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sys (name, value) VALUES ('web', '14')
  END
```

и

```
INSERT IF NOT EXISTS INTO sys (name, value) VALUES ('web', '14')
```

Для оракла ни один не подходит. Помогите с реализацией

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys where name='web')
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sys (name, value) VALUES ('web', '14')
  END
```

под oracle пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно вот так, если надо обойтись чистым `sql`:

```
insert into  sys (name, value)
select 'web', '14' from dual where not exists (select 1 from sys where name = 'web')
```

Так же можно использовать `merge`, он дает больше простора для маневра :

```
merge into sys
using (select 'web' as name, '14' as value from dual) t
on    (sys.name = t.name)
when  not matched then insert(name, value) values(t.name, t.value)
```

Маленький комментарий по названию таблицы. Называть таблицу `SYS` в `Oracle` не желательно, может приводить к интересным последствиям в поведении `IDE`

Comment: @Victorov правильно ли я понимаю что если данное имя не найдено то добавляем в таблицу запись, а если уже существует, то ничего не делаем?

Comment: да, правильно понимаете

Comment: @Victor повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "xpksys". На ms такого нету(

Comment: @Victor когда выполняю ваш запрос на ms то похожая ошибка, а когда свой, то все норм

Comment: Так можно писать в Oracle, но нельзя писать в MS SQL

Comment: Похоже, вам придется использовать разные запросы для Oracle и MS Sql

Comment: но ошибка то под ms и под oracle

Comment: окей разные. главное чтобы рабочие)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70428/discussion-between-viktorov-and--).

Comment: @Victor можете еще помочь?